# Stripe payment incomplete despite payment details being attached?

Tags: go, stripe-payments, subscription

[image]

Using test data I can create a customer and attach a payment method, but all of my subscriptions are left in this state. Here's my code for creating a subscription currently:

```
// StripeCreateSubscription create a new subscription with fixed price for user
func StripeCreateSubscription(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method != "POST" {
        SendResponse(w, utils.MakeError("you can only POST to the stripe create customer route"), http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
        return
    }

    // Decode the JSON payload
    type requestPayload struct {
        PaymentMethodID string `json:"paymentMethodId"`
        PriceID         string `json:"priceId"`
    }

    var payload requestPayload
    if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&payload); err != nil {
        sendSystemError(w, fmt.Errorf("decode request payload: %v", err))
        return
    }

    // Get the user from the context of who made the request
    uid := r.Context().Value("user_id").(int)

    u := models.User{}
    if err := u.FindByID(uid); err != nil {
        sendSystemError(w, fmt.Errorf("find user by id: %v", err))
        return
    }
    if u.StripeCustomerID == "" {
        sendSystemError(w, errors.New("no customer for the user"))
        return
    }

    // Attach the payment method to the customer
    paymentParams := &stripe.PaymentMethodAttachParams{
        Customer: stripe.String(u.StripeCustomerID),
    }

    pm, err := paymentmethod.Attach(
        payload.PaymentMethodID,
        paymentParams,
    )

    if err != nil {
        sendSystemError(w, fmt.Errorf("attaching payment method failed: %v", err))
    }

    // Check if the user has any active subscriptions, and cancel the others if they're adding one.
    listParams := &stripe.SubscriptionListParams{
        Customer: u.StripeCustomerID,
        Status:   "all",
    }
    listParams.AddExpand("data.default_payment_method")

    iter := sub.List(listParams)
    subscriptions := iter.SubscriptionList().Data
    if len(subscriptions) > 0 {
        Log.Info(fmt.Sprintf("%v subscriptions found for %v. Cancelling...", len(subscriptions), u.Username))
        for i := 0; i < len(subscriptions); i++ {
            if subscriptions[i].Status != "canceled" && subscriptions[i].Status != "incomplete_expired" {
                Log.Info(fmt.Sprintf("Cancelling %v. Status %v", subscriptions[i].ID, subscriptions[i].Status))
                subscription, err := sub.Cancel(subscriptions[i].ID, nil)
                if err != nil {
                    sendSystemError(w, fmt.Errorf("cancel subscription: %v", err))
                    return
                }
                Log.Info(fmt.Sprintf("Cancelled %v", subscription.ID))
            }
        }
        Log.Info("Old subscriptions cancelled.")
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    }

    // Create subscription
    subscriptionParams := &stripe.SubscriptionParams{
        Customer: stripe.String(u.StripeCustomerID),
        Items: []*stripe.SubscriptionItemsParams{
            {
                Price: stripe.String(payload.PriceID),
            },
        },
        PaymentBehavior:      stripe.String("default_incomplete"),
        DefaultPaymentMethod: stripe.String(payload.PaymentMethodID),
    }
    subscriptionParams.AddExpand("latest_invoice.payment_intent")
    newSub, err := sub.New(subscriptionParams)
    if err != nil {
        sendSystemError(w, fmt.Errorf("new subscription: %v", err))
        return
    }

    // If everything looks good, then send some info back to the user
    output := map[string]interface{}{
        "subscriptionId": newSub.ID,
        "clientSecret":   newSub.LatestInvoice.PaymentIntent.ClientSecret,
    }
    SendResponse(w, output, 200)
}
```

What do I need to do to get my subscriptions to complete payment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `default_incomplete` like the [fixed-price subscription guide](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscription?ui=elements#create-subscription) shows explicitly keeps the initial invoice unattempted when you create the subscription. To complete the setup, you need to [confirm the payment with the Payment Element](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscription?ui=elements&card-or-payment-element=payment-element#collect-payment) (or [with the Card Element](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscription?ui=elements#complete-payment)) using that client secret from the client-side of your application. You already appear to be sending the `client_secret` back, are you using it?